# Jasper generated Excel file error "Excel found unreadable content in .. "

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

I'm using `Java` and `Jasper` to generate reports in `.xlsx` format.
And I was successful and I have components in my application which create actual reports with data.

recently I was trying to add another component and the report generation was successful , but the generated .xslx file wont open with `MS Excel` or any other.

the code parts are below.

```
    ArrayList<ReportBean> reportBean =  new ArrayList<ReportBean>();

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment;filename=BudgetaryQuote.xlsx");
    response.setContentType("application/xlsx");
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    Report report = new Report(template, "xlsx", reportBean, outStream);
    //Report(String template, String format, ArrayList dataList,OutputStream outputStream) 
    report.generateReport();
```

in generateReport() it has ,

```
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(this.template));  
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.dataList); 
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream); 
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign); 
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);

        if(this.format.equalsIgnoreCase(XLSX)) {

            JRXlsxExporter Xlsxexporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
            Xlsxexporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            Xlsxexporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,  outputStream);
            Xlsxexporter.exportReport();            

        }
```

the .jrxml file (It's pretty much blank)

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="timeSheetDetailedReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4ffef809-ea2d-4533-a0b9-bdd2d055afbe">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```

There is an error like in the image.
`"Excel found unreadable content in filename.xls. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."`

How can I check what is the wrong with the file ?

[image]

Comment: What's printed in console or in logs? Any errors?

Comment: no there are no errors. the file created successfully. but it will not open properly. the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem. But it's not clear.

my code had the below code ,

```
ArrayList<ReportBean> reportBean =  new ArrayList<ReportBean>();
Report report = new Report(template, "xlsx", reportBean, outStream);
report.generateReport();
```

The problem was the ArrayList `reportBean` was empty.  The I add an dummy `ReportBean` to the list and the problem was solved.

**But I have no idea how it solved the problem and why**